If $G$ is torsion-free and $H\triangleleft G$ is abelian with finite index, then $g^n=h^n$ implies $g=h$?
Suppose $G$ is a torsion-free group with $H$ as an abelian normal subgroup of $G$ with finite index. Is it true that if $g \in G$, $h \in H$, and $g^n = h^n$, then $g=h$?
I’m asking this because I’ve reduced a problem of mine to this statement, which I initially thought was obviously true. However, I’m now having trouble justifying why this should be the case, or to disprove it. If it helps, in my context, $G$ is finitely generated, and thus $H$ is free abelian.

Certainly this is false if we don't require $H$ to be a finite-index subgroup of $G$: consider the group presentation $\langle a,b | a^n b^{-n} \rangle$. I'm not sure if there's a way to squeeze this down enough to get $\langle a \rangle$ to be finite index, but this might be a helpful direction to think in.

Oh yes, sorry, the fact that $H$ was abelian just confused me

Let $G=\langle a,b\mid b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\rangle$.
The group $G$ is a torsion-free group and for example $(ab)^2=b^2$, but $ab\neq b$.
This group can be represented by matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Let
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have $G\cong \langle A,B\rangle$. Well, and the subgroup $H=\langle a,b^2\rangle$ is normal and has finite index in $G$.

The second relation in your presentation is redundant - it follows from the first relation.

Yeah, thanks, deleted it.

Very simple and clear example, thanks.
